# Trying to setup update user, description and images are not the same as the user

Tags: php, html

I have set up a user editing system in which you can edit the user details, the details fine expect the images and description it does not match the database. I was wondering if anyone could help me fix this problem. I expect the fields to show what is in the database, then I can edit the fields and press the button and it will update the database.

```html
<?php
 if (isset($_GET['user_profile'])) {
  $edit_user = $_GET['user_profile'];
  $get_user = "select * from admins where admin_id='$edit_user'";
  $run_user = mysqli_query($con,$get_user);
  $row_user = mysqli_fetch_array($run_user);
  $user_id = $row_user['admin_id'];
  $user_name = $row_user['admin_name'];
  $user_pass = $row_user['admin_pass'];
  $user_email = $row_user['admin_email'];
  $user_image = $row_user['admin_image'];
  $user_country = $row_user['admin_country'];
  $user_about = $row_user['admin_about'];
  $user_contact = $row_user['admin_contact'];
  $user_job = $row_user['admin_job'];
 }
?>
<div class="row"><!-- row Begin -->
 <div class="col-lg-12"><!-- col-lg-12 Begin -->
  <ol class="breadcrumb"><!-- breadcrumb Begin -->
   <li class="active"><!-- active Begin -->
    <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard / Edit User
   </li><!-- active Finished --> 
  </ol><!-- breadcrumb Finished -->
 </div><!-- col-lg-12 Finished -->
</div><!-- row Finished -->
<div class="row"><!-- row Begin -->
 <div class="col-lg-12"><!-- col-lg-12 Begin -->
  <div class="panel panel-default"><!-- panel panel-default Begin -->
   <div class="panel-heading"><!-- panel-heading Begin -->
    <h3 class="panel-title"><!-- panel-title Begin -->
     <i class="fa fa-money fa-fw"></i> Edit User
    </h3><!-- panel-title Finished -->
   </div><!-- panel-heading Finished -->
   <div class="panel-body"><!-- panel-body Begin -->
    <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data"><!-- form-horizontal Begin -->
     <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Username</label>
      <div class="col-md-6"><!-- col-md-6 Begin -->
       <input value="<?php echo $user_name; ?>" name="admin_name" type="text" class="form-control" required>
      </div><!-- col-md-6 Finished -->
     </div><!-- form-group Finished -->
     <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label">E-mail</label>
      <div class="col-md-6"><!-- col-md-6 Begin -->
       <input  value="<?php echo $user_email; ?>" name="admin_email" type="text" class="form-control" required>
      </div><!-- col-md-6 Finished -->
     </div><!-- form-group Finished -->
     <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Password</label>
      <div class="col-md-6"><!-- col-md-6 Begin -->
       <input  value="<?php echo $user_pass; ?>" name="admin_pass" type="password" class="form-control" required>
      </div><!-- col-md-6 Finished -->
     </div><!-- form-group Finished -->
     <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Country</label>
      <div class="col-md-6"><!-- col-md-6 Begin -->
       <input  value="<?php echo $user_country; ?>" name="admin_country" type="text" class="form-control" required>
      </div><!-- col-md-6 Finished -->
     </div><!-- form-group Finished -->
     <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Contact</label>
      <div class="col-md-6"><!-- col-md-6 Begin -->
       <input value="<?php echo $user_contact; ?>" name="admin_contact" type="text" class="form-control" required>
      </div><!-- col-md-6 Finished -->
     </div><!-- form-group Finished -->
     <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Job</label>
      <div class="col-md-6"><!-- col-md-6 Begin -->
       <input  value="<?php echo $user_job; ?>" name="admin_job" type="text" class="form-control" required>
      </div><!-- col-md-6 Finished -->
     </div><!-- form-group Finished -->
     <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Image</label>
      <div class="col-md-6"><!-- col-md-6 Begin -->
       <input name="admin_image" type="file" class="form-control" required>
       <img src="admin_images/<?php echo $admin_image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $admin_name; ?>" width="70" height="70">
      </div><!-- col-md-6 Finished -->
     </div><!-- form-group Finished -->
     <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label">About</label>
      <div class="col-md-6"><!-- col-md-6 Begin -->
       <textarea name="admin_about" class="form-control" rows="3"> <?php echo $admin_about; ?></textarea>
      </div><!-- col-md-6 Finished -->
     </div><!-- form-group Finished -->
     <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
      <div class="col-md-6"><!-- col-md-6 Begin -->
       <input name="update" value="Update User" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control">
      </div><!-- col-md-6 Finished -->
     </div><!-- form-group Finished -->
    </form><!-- form-horizontal Finished -->
   </div><!-- panel-body Finished -->
  </div><!-- panel panel-default Finished -->
 </div><!-- col-lg-12 Finished -->
</div><!-- row Finished -->

<?php 
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $user_name = $_POST['admin_name'];
  $user_email = $_POST['admin_email'];
  $user_pass = $_POST['admin_pass'];
  $user_country = $_POST['admin_country'];
  $user_contact = $_POST['admin_contact'];
  $user_job = $_POST['admin_job'];
  $user_about = $_POST['admin_about'];

  $user_image = $_FILES['admin_image']['name'];
  $temp_admin_image = $_FILES['admin_image']['tmp_name'];
  
  move_uploaded_file($temp_admin_image,"admin_images/$user_image");

  $update_user = "update admins set admin_name='$user_name',admin_email='$user_email',admin_pass='$user_pass',admin_country='$user_country',admin_contact='$user_contact',admin_job='$user_job',admin_about='$user_about',admin_image='$user_image' where admin_id='$user_id'";
   $run_user = mysqli_query($con,$update_user);
   if ($run_user) {
    echo "<script>alert('Admin has been updated sucessfully')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.open('login.php','_self')</script>";
    session_destroy();
   }
 }
?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Check with `var_dump($_POST, $_FILES);` the values you receive from the form and if they contain the correct values. Then, check the return value of `mysqli_query/mysqli_prepare()` to see if you have any MySQL errors. If you do, check them with `mysqli_error`